# Bot Problem.How to solve this problem in c?

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, decision-problem

Programming problem:
In BotLand, Robots can understand all words of any combination of letters and letters with leading or trailing (not both) numeric value. Given a word W (string of alphanumeric). Write a function to check if W is Bot word. Don't use library functions/ regex.

Example:

Input: BotLand
Output: Bot word

Input: BotLand77
Output: Bot word

Input: 1Bot2Land3
Output: Non Bot word

Comment: Welcome to CGCC. This site hosts recreational programming challenges, based on an objective winning criterion. (Here, you picked [`code-golf`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf): the shortest answer wins.) It is not designed to get any practical implementation or theoretical answer. So, is it really supposed to be a challenge?

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 33 bytes

```python
lambda s:1-(s[0]+s[-1]).isdigit()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYylBXozjaIFa7OFrXMFZTL7M4JTM9s0RD839BUWZeiUaahrpTfolPYl6KuqYmF7qYuTmKqCE2pSBBI5CoMVD4PwA)

-8 bytes thanks to Grimy and A _

Comment: Python 3, 41 bytes
lambda s:a(s[0])+a(s[-1])>0
a=str.isalpha what is this @Jitse. what is this?

Comment: @MafujShikder it's a program answering your challenge. You can use the Try it online! link to check that it works.

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKi@/RKG4pEgvszglMz2zRKM42iBWuzha1zBW839BUWZeiUaahrpTfolPYl6KuqYmF7qYuTmKqCE2pSBBI5CoMVD4PwA)

Comment: @Jitse please solve this problem n c

Comment: [33B](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYylBXozjaIFa7OFrXMFZTL7M4JTM9s0RD839BUWZeiUaahrpTfolPYl6KuqYmF7qYuTmKqCE2pSBBI5CoMVD4PwA) if you use 1 for true and 0 for false. [32B](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSlejONogVrs4WtcwVlMvszglMz2zREPzf0FRZl6JRpqGulN@iU9iXoq6piYXupi5OYqoITalIEEjkKgxUPg/AA) by abusing predefined true/false values even further.

Comment: @MafujShikder Specific-language competitions are highly discouraged unless in very specific cases and this is not one of those cases.